# Failed to push to Heroku. Don't understand what's wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, bundler

Output:

> ```
> Counting objects: 96, done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 7.87 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 73 (delta 56), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
>        Fixing nokogiri install. Clearing bundler cache.
>        See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/923.
>        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
>        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>        You have added to the Gemfile:
>        * postmark-rails (~> 0.5.2)
>        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
>        * postmark-rails
>        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>
>
>        You have added to the Gemfile:
>        * postmark-rails (~> 0.5.2)
>
>        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
>        * postmark-rails
>  !
>  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>  !
>
>  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
>
> Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
> To git@heroku.com:sutra-staging.git
>  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sutra-staging.git'
> Everything up-to-date
> ```

My `Gemfile.lock` is in version control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say your `Gemfile.lock` is in version control but your error messages are saying that the `Gemfile.lock` doesn't match your `Gemfile`.

You need to `bundle install` locally and commit your modified `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 3):

What has happened is you have changed your Gemfile, but you have not locally updated your gems using Bundler. This means that your `Gemfile` file and your `Gemfile.lock` file are out of sync.

In order to fix this, run `bundle install`, commit your changes, and push again to Heroku. This will install the `postmark-rails` gem that you added, update the `Gemfile.lock` and get everything back in sync again.

What may have confused you is installing gems using `gem install` doesn't update the gems that Bundler is aware of. Bundler's job is to manage the gems for your project, so any time you add a new gem, make sure to run Bundler to update things.